# block current thread for executing, until a variable is updated by another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

my code :

```
    private  AtomicBoolean fetched1 = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private int  rowCount;

    public int getRowCount() {
            data.getRealm().exec(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public  void run() {
                    rowCount = data.size();
                    fetched1.set(true);
                }
            });
            while(!fetched1.get()){
            }
            fetched1.set(false);
            return rowCount;
        }
```

it seems work for me right  now, but I am not familiar with threading(it always confuse me), should I do it like above code any way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> should I do it like above code any way?

This looks to be a spin loop which will use unnecessary CPU.  It is better to use `wait` and `notify` to signal that the data has been fetched.  Something like:

```
   private final Object lock = new Object();
   private volatile Integer rowCount = null;
   ...

      public void run() {
         rowCount = data.size();
         synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
         }
      }

  synchronized (lock) {
     // we loop here in case of race conditions or spurious interrupts
     while (rowCount == null) {
        lock.wait();
     }
  }
  ...
```

I don't think you need a fetched `AtomicBoolean` at all.  You should make the `rowCount` be `volatile` and then you can test its value.  The `while` loop is a good pattern to follow because of producer/consumer race conditions and spurious interrupts.

Comment: I think you are missing a `fetched.set(true);`

Comment: Yeah thanks @Peter.  I removed the need for using fetched at all.

Comment: I would move the field updated/checked into the synchronized block. In this case its simple, but in a more complex case it would be needed.

Comment: Ugh using a negative `rowCount` is kind of ugly, because you are violating an implicit invariant of the problem. Wouldn't it be nicer to use a separate boolean to indicate the row was updated?

Comment: You mean move the `rowCount` assignment @Peter?  I don't think I need that with the `volatile`.  I think I could get rid of the `volatile` if the assignment was in the sync block tho, right?

Comment: I just thought the additional `AtomicBoolean` was unnecessary @Tudor given that we already have a `synchronized` block.  An `Integer` could be used as non-null.

Comment: @Gray: Using a normal `boolean` and assigning it inside the `synchronized` block should suffice in my opinion, since you need `synchronized` anyway to use `wait/notify`.

Comment: Thanks, Gray! which synchronized block will be executed first? If I understand synchronized block correctly,on the same object only one synchronized block can be executed at any time

Comment: Like I said, this is a simple case with one reader and one writer. What if the first block increments the rowCount?

Comment: @CaiNiaoCoder It shouldn't matter. It has to work regardless. In general, the thread already running will reach the block first, the other thread has to start.

Comment: @CalNiaoCoder Peter is right.  It's a race and it shouldn't matter but most likely the outer calling thread will make it first.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems

- the first thread is busy waiting, which is usually undesirable.
- the pattern cannot be extended to more threads as a second thread could try to set the value to true.

Instead the simplest pattern is to lock on an object and wait/notify when the value is changed.